# Output text based on a following element criteria

Tags: jsoup

```
<div class="item-container">
    <h4 class="title">Item 1</h4>
    <h4 class="impact"><i class="exclamation point"></i>Impact:High</h4>
</div>


<div class="item-container">
    <h4 class="title">Item 2</h4>
</div>
```

I am in need of a jsoup master.

I only want to grab the text "Item 1" (only h4's with another class "impact" immediately following it). How do I do this?

So far, I am only able to grab all h4's from the correct class, but am unable to filter the output based on surrounding elements:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class GetItem {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File input = new File("D:\\html.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");

    Elements div = doc.select("div.item-container");
    Elements h4 = doc.select("div.item-container > h4.title");

    for (int i = 0; i < h4.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Item: " + h4.get(i).text());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code (I've tested it with Jsoup 1.9.2):

```
File input = new File("D:\\html.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
Elements h4 = doc.select("div.item-container > h4.title");

for (Element e : h4) {
    if (e.nextSibling() != null && e.nextElementSibling().hasClass("impact")) {
        System.out.println("Item: " + e.text());
}
```

The idea is to get all the `h4` elemnets, like you did, and test for each of them if it has a sibling, and if so - if the sibling has class `impact`.